# TypeScript conditional types constrain no longer working after v3.5.1

Tags: typescript

This works as expected <=v3.3.3 ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.3.3&ssl=3&ssc=79&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwMIHtkGcEEMUAeAFQD4oBeKAbygG0BpKFKAawhEwDMoSBdAFx8m-KBAAewCMgAmOKHiRooAfhGMxw5BABuEeFAC+AKFCQoAdXzJgcZalLipM+YoQpUFasgCuAWwAjAzNwaBIIPCdJaTkFe08sXAJicm9aBmZWDi5eAWFrWwS0UlEKIyA))

```
type StringConstrain<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never }
type WantString<T extends string> = number
type Test<T extends StringConstrain<T>> = { [K in keyof T]: WantString<T[K]> }
```

In 3.5.1 and above, including latest 3.9.2, it reports ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwMIHtkGcEEMUAeAFQD4oBeKAbygG0BpKFKAawhEwDMoSBdAFx8m-KBAAewCMgAmOKHiRooAfhGMxw5BABuEeFAC+AKFCQoAdXzJgcZalLipM+YoQpUFasgCuAWwAjAzNwaBIIPCdJaTkFe08sXAJicm9aBmZWDi5eAWFrWwS0UlEKIyA))

```
Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2344)
```

I don't understand the new behavior and if this is not a bug, what's the intended way of achieving the same type constrain after 3.5.1?